# Is it ok to use phone internet with USB tethering to install the 3rd party softwares and the drivers during the installation of ubuntu?

Tags: networking, drivers, system-installation, usb

My laptop doesn't have any ethernet and I only use my mobile phone data for internet via usb and mo. I came to know that during the installation wireless connection may not work. So please tell me if I can use USB tethering during the installation.

Comment: Yes. What do you think can go wrong?

Comment: Once you setup WiFi before/during installation it works fine during installation in my experience. Installing third party drivers and updates may involve huge downloads. As long as you pay for the mobile data, you should be fine whether you use WiFi or USB tethering.